# Split PyTorch tensor into overlapping chunks

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Given a batch of images of shape (batch, c, h, w), I want to reshape it into (-1, depth, c, h, w) such that the i-th "chunk" of size d contains frames i -> i+d. Basically, using .view(-1, d, c, h, w) would reshape the tensor into d-size chunks where the index of the first image would be a multiple of d, which isnt what I want.

Scalar example:

if the original tensor is something like:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] and d is 2;
```

`view()` would return : `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]];`

however, I want to get:

```
[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[5,6],[6,7],[7,8],[8,9],[9,10],[10,11],[11,12]]
```

I wrote this function to do so:

```
def chunk_slicing(data, depth):
    output = []
    for i in range(data.shape[0] - depth+1):
        temp = data[i:i+depth]
        output.append(temp)
    return torch.Tensor(np.array([t.numpy() for t in output]))
```

However I need a function that is useable as part of a PyTorch model as this function causes this error :

```
RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Tensor that requires grad. Use tensor.detach().numpy() instead.
```

Answer (score 5):

IIUC, You need [`torch.Tensor.unfold`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.unfold.html#torch-tensor-unfold).

```
import torch
x = torch.arange(1, 13)
x.unfold(dimension = 0,size = 2, step = 1)
```

---

```
tensor([[ 1,  2],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 3,  4],
        [ 4,  5],
        [ 5,  6],
        [ 6,  7],
        [ 7,  8],
        [ 8,  9],
        [ 9, 10],
        [10, 11],
        [11, 12]])
```

Another example with `size = 3` and `step = 2`.

```
>>> torch.arange(1, 10).unfold(dimension = 0,size = 3, step = 2)

tensor([[1, 2, 3],  # window with size = 3
# step : ---1--2---
        [3, 4, 5],  # 'step = 2' so start from 3
        [5, 6, 7],
        [7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: If I want to go from shape [64, 1, 36, 36] to [55,10,1,36,36] what size kernel should I use?

Comment: @MohamadMoustafa, Is this help you: `torch.swapaxes(torch.arange(64*36*36).reshape(64,36,36).unfold(dimension = 0,size = 10, step = 1), 1, 3)[:,:,None, :,:].shape`

Comment: @MohamadMoustafa or if `x = [64, 1, 36, 36]` try this : `torch.swapaxes(x.unfold(dimension = 0,size = 10, step = 1), 1, 3)[:,:,None, :,:]`